# Using keyboard commands

Tags: key-bindings

I am Using Emacs GUI on Windows 10 and am having problems entering commands. I am attempting to use `C-h t` and I am getting the error message `C-c h is undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It appears to receive the input `C-c h` to your `C-h` is there a reason that the `c` key will also show? Can you confirm that you type <control h> Followed by a <t>,and not typing the <c> character at all?

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not then bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes then provide a step-by-step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q`, to show the problem.

Comment: Sometimes my `ctrl`, `alt`, and `shift` keys get stuck. As silly as it sounds, maybe you have a stuck key.  I also sometimes have problems with Autohotkey sending weird things.  If you use that, or something like it, try disabling that.